# How can I add the correct variation price in a dropdown in woocommerce depending on its variation type?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

(Hopefully this make sense) 
I need to be able to either display the individual prices of a variation as you go in woocommerce so a customer knows how much the variation difference is or I need the drop down prices to change so that they make sense visually.

I have used the following code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 
'display_price_in_variation_option_name' );
function display_price_in_variation_option_name( $term ) {
global $wpdb, $product;
$result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'" );
$term_slug = ( !empty( $result ) ) ? $result[0] : $term;
$query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
            WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
                AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
                AND products.post_parent = $product->id";
$variation_id = $wpdb->get_col( $query );
$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $variation_id[0] );

if ( $parent > 0 ) {
    $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id[0] );
    $_currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    return $term . ' ('.$_currency.' '. $_product->get_price()  . ')';
}
return $term;
}
```

but as you will see this from this image it does not display correctly and looks a little confusing. 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ9RH.png][1]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the final price is not showing the total of all the variations you have selected?

Comment: **Is not possible** to do that when you have multiple attributes for variations (more than one select field)… Just think about it.